# Dokku and log management

Tags: logging, docker, dokku

I have dokku running on Digital Ocean, and one of my apps is log intensive. What is happening is that the logs are growing up to the HD limit.

One possible solution would be to use logrotate but the log filename is some sort of hash which I assume is created upon the initial deploy, so logrotate would need to be manually configured for every app deployed, which sort of kills the "Your own personal heroku" moto.

Is there any way to tell dokku to rotate or limit the size of log for an app?

Comment: For others interested in this, also see the discussion here: https://github.com/progrium/dokku/issues/417

Answer (score 3):

Though It might be not the answer that you want, I'm runnning rails app in Digital Ocean by Dokku. Since rails application can't be deployed without [rails_12factor gem](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor). This is based on the idea which is logs should be directed to stdout. see: http://12factor.net/logs

If we follow this way, we shouldn't care logs in container as how to rotate. Instead of that, I'm sending logs to [papertrail](https://papertrailapp.com/). They have integration service which stores in S3. So container can be more destroyable and loosely-coupled. What do you think?

Comment: There are open source alternatives to `papertrail` such as Fluentd (http://fluentd.org) and Logstash (http://logstash.net), among others